# Java stopwatch not working

Tags: stopwatch

I am making a rubik's cube timer app and I have a stopwatch function that seems fine to me but just stops the gui doing things properly. It doesn't allow the window to close and doesn't allow the stop button to work. When I have changed the condition of the while loop to something like: "while (seconds < 10) " then my program waits for 10 seconds before displaying the time and allowing me to loop. My guess is that I am creating an infinite loop because action listener cannot work during the loop. Here is the part of my code:

```
public class MyStartListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
            startClock(true);
        }
    }

    public class MyStopListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
            startClock(false);
        }
    }

    public void startClock(boolean t) {
        boolean play = t;
        int minutes=0;
        int seconds=0;
        long milliSeconds=0;
        while (play==true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1);
            } catch(Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            milliSeconds+=1;
            if (milliSeconds==1000) {
                seconds+=1;
                milliSeconds=0;
            }
            if (seconds==60) {
                minutes+=1;
                seconds=0;
            }
            String counting =minutes+":"+seconds+":"+milliSeconds+"";
            text.setText(counting);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're doing all of you're "work" on the GUI thread and so nothing else gets a change to run. Do some googling on Java EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) and so on.

Comment: Thanks, so if I do it on another thread then the gui won't stop and will still check for actions? I'm a novice to java.

Comment: Yep - if you "work" on a "background thread", the GUI will keep processing events. You need to be careful if you have 2 threads trying to change the same variables.

Comment: Thanks, I need to read up on threads. Will it stop when the stop button is clicked and false is passed through the stopwatch?

Comment: I read up on threads but I still don't get how to do this. How do I make the stopwatch run on a different thread while the GUI keeps processing events?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/